# How do I make a split window in cocoa?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'd like to make a window that is split vertically and where the right hand side can slide back and forth. Just like in Xcode 4.1 where the "Hide or show Utilities" button makes the utility windows slide back and forth.

How do I do that with Cocoa?

Thanks,
  jules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you're looking for is called [NSSplitView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start with an NSSplitView, or somebody's improvement like RBSplitView.